# How to programmatically look up google app instances

Tags: google-app-engine

I have implemented instance mem-caches because we have very static data and the memcache is not very reliable and rather slow compared to an instance cache.

However there is some situations where I would like to invalidate the instance caches. Is there any way to look them up?

Example
Admin A updates a large gamesheet on instance A and that instance looks up all other instances and update the data using a simple REST api.

Comment: How did you creating instance memcache, Could you please share some code on this??

Comment: 1) Static hashmap(key,value)  2) all loads from datastore/memcache adds value to instance cache 3) warmup servlet loads data into instance cache 4) a nice wrapper for all of it

Comment: Are you trying to lookup which instances are running or which instance you are in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: you can't.

Unlike [backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/backends/BackendService#getBackendAddress%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), frontend instances are not individually addressable; that is, there is no way for you to make a RESTy URLFetch call to a specific frontend instance. Even if they were, there is no builtin mechanism for enumerating frontend instances, so you would need to roll your own, e.g. keeping a list of live instances in the datastore and adding to it in a warmup request and removing on repeated connect failure. But at that point you've just implemented a slower, more costly, and less available memcache service.

If you moved all the cache services to backends (using your instance-local static, or, for instance, running a [memcached written in Go](http://dustin.github.com/2009/11/12/gomemcached.html) as a different app version), it's true you would gain a degree of control (or at least transparency) regarding evictions. Availability, speed, and cost would still likely suffer.

Comment: well actually keeping my own list would work, since I only need to clear it when the datastore is updated (very very rarely). But yeah a better solution is to create a timeout on my instance cache.